# File streaming in FUSE

Tags: python, streaming, fuse

I am trying to implement a streaming operation on a remote file(media) using Filesystem in userspace.
I am using python-fuse. I have a link of a remote file `link =http://somelink`. I know size of a file and have assigned that size to `Stat` parameter.

I have the code to read specific bytes from a remote file using `range header`.

```
import urllib2

class HttpFile(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.offset = 0
        self._size = -1

    def size(self):
        if self._size < 0:
            f = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
            self._size = int(f.headers["Content-length"])
        return self._size

    def read(self, count=-1):
        req = urllib2.Request(self.url)
        if count < 0:
            end = self.size() - 1
        else:
            end = self.offset + count - 1
        req.headers['Range'] = "bytes=%s-%s" % (self.offset, end)
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        data = f.read()
        # FIXME: should check that we got the range expected, etc.
        chunk = len(data)
        print chunk, count
        if count >= 0:
            assert chunk <= count
        self.offset += chunk
        return data

    def seek(self, offset, whence=0):
        if whence == 0:
            self.offset = offset
        elif whence == 1:
            self.offset += offset
        elif whence == 2:
            self.offset = self.size() + offset
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid whence")
```

Now in `open` operation of a FUSE. I have created an object of `HttpFile`:

```
def open(self, path, flags):
        self.h = HttpFile(link)
```

I have written a `read` operation to return required bytes `[offset,size]`.

```
def read(self, path, size, offset):
        self.h.seek(offset,whence=0)
        x=self.h.read(size)
        return x
```

When I mount this file system and invoke `cat somefilename` or `gedit somefilename` it works  great if the `link` corresponds to the text file. However if the link is of music file and when I try to invoke `vlc somefilename`, vlc plays the song for few seconds and then it crashes.

How do I modify `read()` function so that it would work for media files.?

Comment: did you progress on this?  I am looking for something like `s3backer`, but for arbitrary HTTP servers supporting byte ranges. See also `smoothfs`.

Comment: Yes. Apparently I solved this problem at the time, looking at what went wrong in logs. Looking at this question almost after a year, I don't even remember this :D.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I din't even bother about reading a whole file. I wrote my own linux application (launcher) which was a wrapper over VLC. I wrote a code to open a link in VLC in this launcher.